# flatpak not working - apparently GPG issue

Tags: gnupg, arch, flatpak

On a fresh Arch Linux install, I have difficulties to make flatpak work.
It seems it's due to a GPG issue but I can't figure out what I did wrong.
I cleared the caches, uninstalled & reinstalled, to no avail.

Here is an expression of the symptom:

```
$ flatpak remote-ls flathub
error: Unable to load summary from remote flathub: Signature made Mon Jan 24 18:48:35 2022 using RSA key ID 562702E9E3ED7EE8
Can't check signature: public key not found
```

Please note that the user profile has been restored from a backup (incl. its GPG keys). I checked GPG seems functional.
Any clue?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I found that I was missing the corresponding trusted key in /var/lib/flatpak/repo/flathub.trustedkeys.gpg. I copied it from a VM of mine and now it works.
But why was the trusted key missing in first instance?